# Update dynamic control inside a updatepanel with a dynamic created child

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

I've been searching how to acomplish this but I have'nt been able to find a solution. I simplified the problem from my original project where I have to achieve this to the following:

In the .aspx I have:

```
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
     </asp:ScriptManager>
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpDynamicControls" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder" runat="server">
            </asp:PlaceHolder>
        </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And in code behind:

```
     public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
          protected string TextToShow
          {
              get
              {
                return Session["TextToShow"] == null ? "Original Text" : 
                                                        Session["TextToShow"].ToString();
              }
              set { Session["TextToShow"] = value; }
           }

           protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
             var lblToChange = new Label
                          {
                              ID = "lblToChange",
                              Text = TextToShow
                          };

             var chkChangeText = new CheckBox
                            {
                                ID = "btnChangeText",
                                Text = "Change Text",
                                AutoPostBack = true
                            };
             chkChangeText.CheckedChanged += ChkChangeTextClick;

             PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(lblToChange);
             PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(chkChangeText);
         }

         private void ChkChangeTextClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             var check = (CheckBox) sender;

             TextToShow = check.Checked ? "Text Changed" : "Original Text";
             udpDynamicControls.Update();
         }


         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

         }

      }
```

As you can see what i'm trying to do si to update the label when the check box is changed threw the update panel. But the udpDynamicControls.Update(); Doesnt fire the page_init event, where it would take its new value. I already checked out similar questions but I believe this is a diferent scenario.

I will be very thankfull to anybody that could help. I apologize for any bad english.

Comment: If there is some other way of achieving this functionality without the use of an updatepanel but avoiding a posback on the browser, please I welcome any advice. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved my problem on my original project some other way, but I thought I might as well post the answer to what I did in case somebody has the same problem, the they might use the same solution.

Since I was depending on the page_init to run again after the update just to update the new value for my control and this wasn't happing, then a possible solution would be to update the value of the control in the check box changed event, where as the label is already created, and in the next page life cycle run, it would persist its value.

So the only thing I changed was the ChkChangeTextClick Event and the end result was:

```
      protected void ChkChangeTextClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        var check = (CheckBox) sender;

        TextToShow = check.Checked ? "Text Changed" : "Original Text";
        ((Label) PlaceHolder.FindControl("lblToChange")).Text = TextToShow;

       }
```

Replacing:

```
       udpDynamicControls.Update();
```

For:

```
        ((Label) PlaceHolder.FindControl("lblToChange")).Text = TextToShow;
```

Come to think about it, its a more simple approach, in my original project I have several dynamic controls and I just set a pattern in my controls ID to find the ones I need and change the values. The events of the controls don't get lost and I can show the updated information without the browser postback.

I hope this is of any help to anyone in the future, because I almost ripped all my hair out with this.